# Restrict communication to server only from the right client

Tags: android, security, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I am pretty confused here trying to find a solution to this problem.

There is a wifi enabled micro controller and a client (android app), both connected to the same wifi network. The official android app sends some instructions to the microcontroller through GET params.

Now i want only and only the official app to be able to send meaningful data across. To prevent man-in-the-middle attack i can encrypt this data using asymmetric keys. The micro-controller will generate the public and private keys and give out the public key through the server when asked for.

But then comes the problem. Can't the attacker send data to the device (micro-controller) too if he knows the public key? The attacker can simply get the code of the app through reverse eng. and send meaningful data through his browser to the device.

Some limitations -

1. I cant make any sort of white-list on the device.
2. There is no internet connection. Just LAN available.
3. The device has no sense of time.

Some properties-

1. The devices have a unique 8 digit id. In scenario of multiple devices, the right one is targeted using this id. The devices' used IP address is mapped to this ID.
2. The android app (client) sends numeric strings in GET params for the devices to perform operations.

Can this be solved using a fool-proof method?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, that's not solvable. You can only do some obfuscation and hope that nobody is determined enough to break your app.

Comment: Umm, Anybody else?

Comment: can you use https? is there wireless encryption on the wifi? If both, i don't think mitm is a big concern. if not, then use shared secrets to authenticate; send a token and a hash of the token and the secret. You can still get replay attacks, but that's much better than  getting everything.

Comment: I unfortunately cant use https. And even a replay attack will be equally bad for the situation.

Comment: You could have each microcontroller generate an RSA keypair and let it distribute the **private key** to your app through some physical media.  Would still be a bit of setup involved for the user though.